# How to deploy a Vue.js application on Node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a dist folder containing CSS, fonts, JS folder and an `index.html` file minimized for Vue.js, ready to deploy and use. I want to use Node.js to run this application. **How can I set this up to just run `npm run server` and have it deployed on a specific port requested?** Not sure how to structure this or if I need to build it in a specific way to run this Vue app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in the development mode you are using `npm run serve` and you search another command to deploy?

Comment: I'm curious how to set this (dist folder/Vue App) up to run on a specific port. Doesn't matter if it is dev or production at this point. Just want to be able to view it, while it set up to run on Node using `npm run` (server or server-dev) script

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since Vue is only a frontend library, the easiest way to host it and do things like serve up assets is to create a simple Express friendly script that you can use to start a mini-web server. Read up quickly on [Express](https://expressjs.com/) if you haven’t already. After that, add express:

```
npm install express --save
```

Now add a `server.js` file to your project’s root directory :

```
// server.js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + "/dist"));
var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
var hostname = '127.0.0.1';

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
   console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
 });
```

after that you could run :

```
 node server
```

and your project will be served at the given host and port

Assuming that you have already the `dist` directory, if you don't have it run :

```
npm run build
```

in order to generate it

Comment: Perfect explanation. Exactly what I needed to get it going. I do use express for the back end, so this made a lot of sense. Thank you