# vue CLI 3 public path deploying in webserver

Tags: vue.js

Our `vue` application has to be deployed in a web server in a relative path...something like `student.com/myvueapp/`

so in my `vue` app , i put public path as `myvueapp`

and in `vue.config.js` :

```
 module.exports = {
      publicPath: '/myvueapp/'
    }
```

It works in the subpath , when i do `vue-cli-service` serve .But when i do build and use the assets ,it doesn't work. I 
I went to `dist` directory after building and ran  `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000` it fails.

How should i fix it ? should i set some other properties other than public path? 
I put it into our dev server `nginx` , but there also it doesn't work.

Comment: what are you using as server?

Comment: Nginx in DEV environment. I am curious why doesnt it work in local

Comment: try  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229626/how-to-deploy-a-vue-js-application-on-node/52230661#52230661) using node

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/static-server I tried this..it doesnt work when publicPath is specified and when i use build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `build` task will only build your app's root directory. The paths within the file will be correct for your configured `publicPath` though, eg

```html
<!-- in dist/index.html -->
<script src=/myvueapp/js/app.0fcf91de.js></script>
```

The idea is that you take the contents of your `dist` folder and deploy it to `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/myvueapp/` on your production HTTP server.

For example, if your NGINX config has

```
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
```

you would create the directory `/usr/share/nginx/html/myvueapp` and copy the contents of `dist` into that.

---

If you're trying to run it locally, you'll still need to manually create a folder (or symbolic link) for your `publicPath`.

```sh
# in some directory

# create a symlink
ln -s path/to/your/app/dist myvueapp
# or create a real folder, eg
# mkdir myvueapp && cp -a path/to/your/app/dist/* myvueapp/

# start your server
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

then open `http://localhost:8000/myvueapp/`.

Comment: What all things should i do in nginx

Comment: @Janier I've added an nginx example

Comment: I tried it..only difference is i have to start the server outside the directory..so if i have mydir/myvueapp ... I have to be in mydir and start the webserver..is that right?

Comment: That's right. Your web server's document root (the local filesystem path corresponding to `/`) must have relative access to `myvueapp`