# How to deploy Vue app with Node Backend app on Linux(RHEL)?

Tags: node.js, apache, vue.js, rhel, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a vue project with Node back-end.
The architecture is simple, APIs are exposed by Node which are cosumed by Vue fornt-end.
In developent environment vue dev server runs on port 8080 and the Node server runs on port 3000. The api calls from Vue are being redirected to port 3000 using following devServer configuration in vue.config.js

```
devServer: {
     proxy:{
       '/api/*':{
         target: 'http://localhost:3000'
       }
     }
   }
```

I want to deploy this app on RHEL server but unable to find the proper configuration.
I deployed vue app on **apache** and ran the server simply using **node server.js**.

How to achieve porxy similar to dev environment? I tried Ngnix for proxy with  no success so far.

Need help with approach.

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229626/how-to-deploy-a-vue-js-application-on-node/52230661#52230661

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I want to keep node instance and vue instance separate. I had tried something like this but it did not work.