# Deploying Vue App Locally and Out of Sandbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, zeromq

Is there any way to deploy a VueJS app locally without having it limited by the browser?

I want the user to be able to call the application from the command line, for example `app_name --port 6000`, and then be able to load up the app from `http://127.0.0.1:6000` or any other port they selected. The important thing is, the Vue App must be able to import and use native NodeJS modules, such as `fs` and `zeromq`.

Comment: please check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229626/how-to-deploy-a-vue-js-application-on-node/52230661#52230661)

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Thank you for your comment, but the linked suggestion is using a secondary ExpressJS process. VueJS doesn't have access to the native modules, and an API interface needs to sit between the two.

Comment: Vuejs or any other front end framework, cannot have a direct access to the hardware as long as they are running inside a browser environment.
You can use **Electron** though, to wrap your Vuejs app into a desktop application. It also gives you a separate process exclusively for accessing your hardware.

Comment: @evolon I was using Electron, but it comes along with a ton of stuff that I don't need.

Comment: Then you should probably bring up a simple node server and make requests from browser via http.

Answer (score 1):

Vuejs code must run in a browser environment in which you don't have access to your hardware. So basically you have three options to achieve this:

#### 1. Use Electron

Electron gives you a chromium instance in which your UI (Vuejs) code can run and a separate process in which you can have access to your hardware using nodejs.

#### 2. Create a simple http server with node

In this case you need to create a server with nodejs. For example you can create a file named `server.js` like this:

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs')

http.createServer((req, res) => {

   // Do something with fs
   const data = fs.readFileSync('path/to/some/file');

   // return back the data with http
   http.writeHead(200, {ContentType: 'text/plain'})
   http.write(data);
}).listen(8000)
```

And fetch the data in your Vuejs app with http like this:

```
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      myData: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSomeAction () {
      const {data} = await axios.get('localhost:8000')
      this.myData = data;
    }
  }
}
```

Now in your package.json you can put this to run both when `npm serve` is called:

```
...

"scripts": {

  ...

  "serve": "node server.js & vue-cli-service serve"
}
```

#### 3. Use Nuxt

In case **you need to do something with your hardware ONCE, and BEFORE the render** you can use Nuxt to access the hardware before rendering the Vuejs app and handing it over to your browser.