# vue-cli: dist/js/ is not found in website source

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

**Problem:** I'm building a website with vue-CLI. When I run the dev server with `npm run serve` everything displays the way it should.  After running `npm run build` a `/dist` folder is being created. Then when running `npm start` and starting the localhost server, in website source, instead of all js files in `dist/js` only `app.d574a975.js` is being shown (however all other js files are present in `/dist` directory locally) and, therefore, when accessing `localhost:5000` (my port is `5000`) I'm getting `localhost/:1 GET http://localhost:5000/js/chunk-vendors.3fcb4836.js/ net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` error and the page goes blank. Is there a way to fix this? I'm quite new to web development, so I will appreciate any help.

**May be important:**

- I've already tried deploying it on the localhost and it worked just fine. However, then I tried adding middleware to handle the `404` error and since then the app has been misbehaving and printing out the above-mentioned error in the console.
- I've tried rebuilding the app from ground up by recreating vue app with `vue create`, reinstalling same dependencies and copypasting the code from original project. And for some unknown reason it worked just fine, the `dist/js` had all files in it.

**Project folder architecture:**

[image: Project folder architecture]

**server.js**:

```js
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const path = require('path')
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit')

let app = express();
const port = 5000;

const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 300 
})
app.use(limiter)
app.set('trust proxy', 1)

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use('/api/hometasks', require('./api/hometask'))
app.use('/api/auth', require('./api/auth'))
app.use('/api/groups', require('./api/groups'))
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/')))
app.listen(port)
```

**main.js**

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import App from './App.vue'
import Main from './components/corepages/main.vue'
import PageNotFound from './components/infopages/pageNotFound.vue'

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {path: '/', component: Main},
        {path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', component: PageNotFound}
    ]
})

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: Looks like something with your `dist`integration is going wrong. Have you looked at this related question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229626/how-to-deploy-a-vue-js-application-on-node-js-server

Comment: @TKsomewhat I've looked into it, tried using serveStatic instead of express.static, but the `404` issue remains the same

Comment: I've also tried placing `server.js` in the core directory, outside the server directory, and also adding `hostname`, but the problem remained the same: it places only one file inside `dist/js` instead of three

Comment: To begin with I'd recommend vite over webpack for development, cause it's much faster. Also have you tried to completely make a new setup? I'm not a node specialist too, but never had problems running Vue with node.

Comment: @TKsomewhat good point on making everything from ground up again, but I still want to understand why would my current project work so incorrectly. Also, thanks, I will be probably switching to Vite, since this kind of problem is present with webpack.

Comment: Try moving static serve route before all API routes. Also can you please share file content for vue.config.js

Answer (score 1):

2022/03 I had this issue with vue3 cli default setup: if you run "npm run build", you get a nice /dest folder with an index.html and correct sub folders. But the js source links go for absolute path /, so this WORKS ONLY IN THE ROOT DIRECTORY of a webserver.

See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

"By default, Vue CLI assumes your app will be deployed at the root of a domain, e.g. https://www.my-app.com/. If your app is deployed at a sub-path, you will need to specify that sub-path using this option. For example, if your app is deployed at https://www.foobar.com/my-app/, set publicPath to '/my-app/'."

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've resolved everything by just following the set up process (same steps, same everything), again. Also, clearing build cache helped when I encountered the same issue and didn't want to recreate the project.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I would take.

First, Move your server folder to your `public`, that way your servers files are included in your `dist` build. You may need to update routes/path etc. This can also be done using `publicPath` https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#baseurl. Alternatively, you can edit your `vue.config.js` and tell webpack to load additional directories into your dist build, however I am not sure if webpack needs to be involved in building your server, I could be wrong Im not sure about your specific setup. https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#static-assets-handling

Next, run `npm run build` to build your dist directory.

Then run `npm install -g serve` and serve your production build using `serve -s dist`

Source: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#general-guidelines